# App Attribution not displayed on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using SSO in my application, and I see my application in Facebook for iPhone "Apps" section, and when tapping on it it launches my app. [This is normal](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#applinks) and works perfectly. Now, when I use a feed dialog on my App to publish a feed story, I do not see the App Attribution next to the "via APP_NAME" like I should. I also marked my app as "SSO enabled" in the apps settings.

[image]

Do you have any idea why it's not showing up the little icon to launch my app on the iOS device?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After facing the same issue i finally got it to work. You need to make sure that in your facebook app settings you have set the "app namespace" under the "Basic Info" section. After I've set it, it took several minutes to propagate throughout their servers but then it worked for all the stories published by the app.

Comment: What do you put in there? com.yourcompany.yourapp? Or something different? Do you have to add the chosen namespace in your iOS code? Thanks!

Comment: you can set any string, as long as it unique. in my case it was "myappname"

Comment: And you just need to set that up in the Facebook.com admin, not in the app itself? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, just on the Facebook app settings (assuming that your Facebook app is used by a native iOS app alone, and there is no use in the open graph API)

Comment: even after setting namespace in basic settings I can't see that little icon ?

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work in my case... Anyone else with this problem?