# App post attribution not displayed anymore in Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I've just noticed that Facebook has stopped attributing the posts mede using their API, but I'm not sure if it is a misconfiguration problem or a decision made by them. I've tried various Apps, old APIs, filled missing fields in the Facebook App configurations and nothing has helped.

[image]

If anyone has encountered the same problem or if their apps still show attribution and wants to share this information, that would be great...

Comment: How are you posting to the API?

Comment: In the end I found a solution... I used the method: [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController: withContent:content delegate:]; And switched to manually instantiate FBSDKShareDialog using the FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet mode. I will post an answer in a second. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After testing testing different approaches to try to solve the problem I found one. First I filled all the fields in the Basic Settings of every App in the Facebook App settings. Mainly the Namespace and App Domains fields where incomplete as said here: [App Attribution not displayed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961569/app-attribution-not-displayed-on-ios) 
But this alone did not help much and in fact it worked until just a few months ago.

For the me the solution has come switching from:

```
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:[eUtils rootViewController] withContent:content delegate:[self sharedInstance]];
```

to

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog=[FBSDKShareDialog new];    
dialog.shareContent=content;
dialog.delegate=[self sharedInstance];
dialog.fromViewController=[eUtils rootViewController];
dialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;
[dialog show];
```

The key was to set the mode to **dialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;**